# I am using PHP and I have a backend form where the user must enter a letter using

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, strlen

I have a backend form where the user must enter a letter using centurion letters such as ARESTU. I have already posted the word over to the PHP life and have used the is_numeric function to make user that the user enters a word and not aa number.

I know want to be able to convert the word to uppercase. I need to find the length of the word that the user has entered which I have already done using the strlen function. I know have to give each letter a value such as a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc.

I then need to check each letter in turn to see which letter the user  has used from the letters they were given. If the user uses a letter that is not in the word then that letter is not given a value.  I then want to be able to display display each letter of the word with the value.

Here is an example of what I want it to look like

If the user enters the word 'are'

- A= 1
- R= 18
- E= 5

Total letter number is 24

Here is the code I have so far, this code only gets the word the user enters from the post, displays the word and shows the number of letters in the word.

```
<? php

$word = $_POST["word"];

$product = 1;


strtoupper($word);
print "$word <br> ";

if (is_numeric($word)) {
  print "Please enter a word";
}


$test = strlen($word);
print "Number of letters in the word are $test";

$lettersArray = array(
  'a' = 1,
  'e' = 5,
  'r' = 18,
  's' = 19,
  't' = 20,
  'u' = 21,
  'other' = 0,
);


$valueString = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
  $letter = strtolower(substr($string, $i, 1));
  $valueString. = $lettersArray[$letter];
}




$product = $product * $word;

?>
```

Comment: what you want exactly? and what are you getting?

Comment: are you search for the `ord()` function to convert chars into the ascii number? [docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

Comment: Your array is wrong , you should use "=>" insted of "=" in arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her is your code with modification

***`EDIT 2`***

```
$word = "ARE";
$product = 1;
strtoupper($word);
print "$word <br> ";

if (is_numeric($word)) {
  print "Please enter a word";
}

$test = strlen($word);
print "Number of letters in the word are $test <br>";

$lettersArray = array(
  'a' => 1,
  'e' => 5,
  'r' => 18,
  's' => 19,
  't' => 20,
  'u' => 21,
  'other' => 0,
);

$valueString = 0;
$assignednumberalpha = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
  $letter = strtolower($word[$i]);
  $valueString = $valueString+$lettersArray[$letter];
  $assignednumberalpha .= "$letter =".$lettersArray[$letter].'<br>';;
}

$product = $product * $word;

echo $assignednumberalpha;
echo "The final Result : $valueString";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot the only thing I am now trying to do is display is to try and brake the word down so that when the user enters the word into the backend form and clicks the submit button not only is the word display but it displays a = 2 if the word has two a's as in apple of if the user enters a letter that is not in the word then it comes up as other.

Comment: @RebekahShaw two a's in apple huh ? anyways you want to show the number assigned to word when user enters it right ?

Comment: haha its to early for me, I should have said to p's but yes you are right that is what i want to do

Comment: @RebekahShaw check now, is that you require ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<? php

$word = $_POST["word"];

$product = 1;


strtoupper($word);
print "$word <br> ";

if (is_numeric($word)) {
print "Please enter a word";
}


$test = strlen($word);
print "Number of letters in the word are $test";

// Your array
$lettersArray = array(
  'a' => 1,
  'e' => 5,
  'r' => 18,
  's' => 19,
  't' => 20,
  'u' => 21,
  'other' => 0,
);

// convert word into lower case or upper case
$word = strtolower($word);

// Split each chars of word and store in array
$chars = str_split($word);


// find the total in foreach or any other loop
foreach ($chars as $char)
{
   if(key_exists($char, $lettersArray))
      $product  = $product  *  $lettersArray[$char];
}

echo $product;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = ['a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'e' => 7, 'r' => 8, 't' => 9];
function myfunc($array, $word)
{
    $tmp = [];
    $word = strtolower($word);
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++)
        $tmp[] = $array[$word[$i]];

    return array_sum($tmp);
}

print_r(myfunc($array, 'bat'));
```

Comment: First it's unreadable. Second: how does this answer the question? Third: must you spam your website as well? flagging as spam.